# CSS bbPress issue on Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, bbpress

I've been banging my head against a brick wall with this one...

I am trying to remove (or hide) the bullet points from the bbPress forum on my WP Theme.

Here is the link: http://yorkshirechess.org/forums/forum/chess-in-yorkshire/

I have tried every css way I can think of such as the obvious:

```
list-style-type: none !important;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a "background" in there:

```
/* style.css - line 931 */
.entry-content ul li {
background: url(images/dot.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
padding: 3px 0 3px 10px; }
```

so just add

```
background: none!important;
```

to your rule and its done.